# How to represent a limit of detection using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot numeric values with defined upper/lower limits of quantification, where values outside of the linear range are reported as "<LLOQ" or ">ULOQ".

```
df = data.frame(values = c('>10', '8.8', '4', '6', '<2', '2.5', '<2'), 
                timepoint = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

Short of replacing the "<2" values with "1" & forcing the vector into a numeric, is there a way to plot these values in such a way that the LLOQ value falls below the lower limit on the plot (ideally, at a "<LLOQ" tick on the axis) and where ULOQ falls somewhere above the upper limit (again, ideally at a ">ULOQ" tick)?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = timepoint, y = values) +
       geom_point() +
       scale_y_???
```

I've tried manually forcing the LLOQ to 1/2 LLOQ and the ULOQ to ULOQ + some arbitrary value (see below), but this is far from an elegant or well-automated solution.

```
df2 = data.frame(values = c(11, 8.8, 4, 6, 1, 2.5, 1), 
                 timepoint = c(1:7))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = timepoint, y = values)) +
       geom_point() + 
       scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11), 
                          labels = c("<2.0", "2", "4", "6", "8", 
                                     "10", ">10"))
```

Comment: Could you include a sketch of your expected graph?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(values = as.numeric(sub(">10", "11", sub("<2", "1", values)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = timepoint, y = values)) +
  annotate("rect", ymin = c(-Inf, 10), ymax = c(2, Inf), xmin = c(-Inf, -Inf),
           xmax = c(Inf, Inf), fill = "red3", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(2, 10), linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(color = values > 10 | values < 2), size = 3, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
                     labels = c("LLOQ", 4, 6, 8, "ULOQ")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red4"), guide = "none") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]